# Force https + Hide sub folder

Tags: php, sql-server, .htaccess

My site folder is www.domain.com/public/
I've create a redirect to this folder in the htaccess  but I would like to force https and hide the subfolder from the address bar too.

Redirect and subfolder hiding are working bur the https isn't, could you help me, many thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.newlabeventi.it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: To clarify, you are linking to the URL without the `/public` subdirectory? Presumably `newlabeventi.it` is an unrelated domain? Can't immediately see why it wouldn't redirect to HTTPS. What happens? Any error? Incidentally, `%{REQUEST_URI} !^public` will _always_ evaluate to _true_, since `REQUEST_URI` starts with a slash.

Comment: I'm redirecting all request to to www.domain.com/public , but the subfolder /public has been hided in the browser address bar. Now it's work fine, but I want to force it to https.